# Caching an expression within an Angular 2 template?

Tags: angular

Within an Angular 2 template, I render a link only if it exists:

```
<a *ngIf="row.getContinent(3).getCountry(22).birds()['pengion'].getLink()"
    class="bird-link"
    href="{{ row.getContinent(3).getCountry(22).birds()['pengion'].getLink() }}">
  Examine this bird.
</a>
```

As you see, the expression for the link (`row.getContinent(3).getCountry(22).birds()['pengion'].getLink()`) is long. Could I somehow define that expression once in my template and reuse it?

Comment: Just write a method or an [accessor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors) on the class.

Comment: Regarding your question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40496/18147, some policy has changed and it should now be eligible to be reopened. Do you want to cast a reopen vote so that we can try to reopen it?

Answer (score -1):

```ts
yourVar: any = row.getContinent(3).getCountry(22).birds()['pengion'].getLink();
```

```html
<a *ngIf="yourVar"
    class="bird-link"
    href="{{ row.getContinent(3).getCountry(22).birds()['pengion'].getLink() }}">
  Examine this bird.
</a>
```

Comment: Please post content only in English, you are not currently on [es.so].